# FPDI FPDF - cell formatting

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to put the next cell unter the upper spacer. The next cell should be under the upper spacer and not added to the right..but I can´t find any solution for this...maybe tables are an option if there is no solution for this...but i would like to try this with cells.

I use FPDI, because i want to add some form data into a PDF Document.

[image: How i want it]

```
$pdf->addPage();#$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);     
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$pdf->Cell(20,265,"Spacer left",1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(160,18,'Upper spacer ',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,18,'Data1',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,18,'Data2',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,18,'Data3',1,0,'C');
```

But as i said, the third cell was added to the right of Upper Spacer.

Spacer left and upper spacer are displayed allright...

I hope anyone can help me figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with

```
$pdf->Ln(XX);
```

XX=value in mm...i can pull everything where i want it...but it´s very time intense....

Thanks to everyone for reading!

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Ln(18);
$pdf->Cell(20,0,'',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(18,10,'TEXT',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(18,10,'TEXT T',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(36,10,'TEXT T',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(36,10,'TEXT T',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(9,10,'',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(36,10,'TEXT',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(9,10,'22',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->Cell(19,0,'',0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(29,10,'x',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(80,10,'x',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'asfasf',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(9);
```